# Unable to redirect to page after successful login into Azure AD using SAML

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, sustainsys-saml2

I have created an .Net Core app to communicate Azure AD with SAML request to enable Single Sign-On. After successful login, it shows me an error as below.

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> KeyNotFoundException: The given key 'Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.EntityId' was not present in the dictionary.
> System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.get_Item(TKey key)

> KeyNotFoundException: No Idp with entity id "https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxx/" found.
> Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.IdentityProviderDictionary.get_Item(EntityId entityId)

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // we need to associate SHA1/SHA256 with the long web-based names for Sustainsys.Saml2 to work
    System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RsaPkCs1Sha256SignatureDescription), System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA256Url);
    System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RsaPkCs1Sha1SignatureDescription), System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA1Url);

    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = Sustainsys.Saml2.AspNetCore2.Saml2Defaults.Scheme;
    })
    .AddSaml2(options =>
    {
        options.SPOptions = new Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.SPOptions()
        {
            AuthenticateRequestSigningBehavior = Sustainsys.Saml2.Configuration.SigningBehavior.Never,
            EntityId = new Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.EntityId(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Saml2:EntityId")),
            MinIncomingSigningAlgorithm = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Saml2:MinIncomingSigningAlgorithm"),
        };

        // We need to use a cert for Sustainsys.Saml2 to work with logout, so we borrow their sample cert
        // https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/blob/develop/Samples/SampleAspNetCore2ApplicationNETFramework/Sustainsys.Saml2.Tests.pfx
        string certFile = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), Configuration.GetValue<string>("Saml2:cert"));
        options.SPOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(certFile));

        // The Azure AD B2C Identity Provider we use
        options.IdentityProviders.Add(
          new Sustainsys.Saml2.IdentityProvider(
            new Sustainsys.Saml2.Metadata.EntityId(Configuration.GetValue<string>("Saml2:IdpEntityId")), options.SPOptions)
          {
              MetadataLocation = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Saml2:IdpMetadata"),
              LoadMetadata = true
          });
    })
    .AddCookie();

    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
        options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
    });
    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

**appSettings.json**

```
{
  "Saml2": {
    "cert": "Sustainsys.Saml2.Tests.pfx",
    "EntityId": "https://localhost:44322/Saml2",
    "MinIncomingSigningAlgorithm": "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1",
    "IdpEntityId": "https://sts.windows.net/{tenantid}/",
    "IdpMetadata": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is conflict between entity id with the path of the metadata. The metadata is exposed at the address that is the entity id, but if you put the metadata locally you need to separate them.

And also check with the `EntityId` of the `IdentityProvider` is correct or not

```
var idp = new IdentityProvider(new EntityId(Entity ID), spOptions) 

{ 

  MetadataLocation = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Saml2:IdpMetadata"), 

}
```

Another way is load the metadata directly from the idp

```
var idp = new IdentityProvider(new EntityId("EntityID"), spOptions) 

{ 

  LoadMetadata = true, 

  AllowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse = true, 

};
```